# K Permutations, 7 letter string, alphabet, no repeats

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Number of 7 letter strings with no repeated letters can be formed from the english alphabet?

I get $$p(26,19)$$ so $$26! / 19!$$

but my answer sheet says it's:

$$ p(26,7) = 26\times25\times24\times23\times22\times21\times20$$

Can somebody confirm to me which ones correct please?

Comment: Here is a simple way to do this:  You have 26 choices for the first letter, and then 25 choices for the second letter (since repeated letters are not allowed), 24 choices for the third letter, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming in your notation that you mean $p(26,7) = \binom{26}{7}$ and $p(26,19) = \binom{26}{19}$;

$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

Hence;

$$\binom{26}{7} = \frac{26!}{7!19!}$$
$$\binom{26}{19} = \frac{26!}{19!7!}$$

Which are the same.

Note that $\frac{26!}{19!} \not = \frac{26!}{7!}$

Answer (score 3):

Both of your answers are equivalent, and therefore correct. By definition of factorial,
$$\frac{26!}{19!}=\frac{26\times 25\times \dots \times 1}{19\times 18\times\dots\times 1}=26\times 25\times 24\times 23\times 22\times 21\times 20.$$

Comment: Could you explain how p(26,7) is equivalent? as 26! / 19! and 26! / 7! give me completely different answers on a calculator?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what your definition of $p(x,y)$ is, but I'm pointing out that $26!/19!=26\times 25\times\dots\times 20$.

Comment: Oh okay I understand, It's defined as 


P(n,k)=n(n−1)(n−2)...(n−k+1)= n! / (n-k)!.


The dot at the end is level with the top of the ! in my book, unsure what it means

Comment: Okay, then $P(26,7)$ is correct and $P(26,19)$ is wrong, by this definition.

Comment: Would it be possible to get an explanation as to how I would work it out? Im sorry to be a pain I just can't get my head around it.
Like I can see how 26! / 19! gets me my answer but I can't do the same using this definition

Comment: Sure, so by the definition in your book, $P(26,7)$ equals $26\times (26-1)\times (26-2)\times\dots\times(26-7+1)=26\times 25\times\dots\times 20$. Does that explain it?

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it, I gotta be honest I do prefer the definition I used to calculate it originally, much more simple in my eyes haha

Answer (score 2):

For unordered string
$$\binom{26}{7}=\binom{26}{26-7}=\binom{26}{19}$$
for ordered 7-leter string
$$\frac{26!}{(26-7)!}=\frac{26!}{19!}$$
for ordered 19-leter string
$$\frac{26!}{(26-19)!}=\frac{26!}{7!}$$
as you ccan see $$\frac{26!}{19!}\neq\frac{26!}{7!}$$